# HTML Table Row Height Problem (height="x" vs style="height:x")

Tags: html, css, html-table

Using Chrome on Windows 10, this code "works", in the sense that it creates an empty row that is 100px tall...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="content" style="width:100%;border:1px solid black">
      <tr id="topRow" height="100" style="width:100%;"></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

... but the following doesn't, in that it generates a very short row, certainly not 100 pixels tall ...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="content" style="width:100%;border:1px solid black">
      <tr id="topRow" style="width:100%;height=100px"></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to use the latter form since the former is deprecated (if not obsolete).

What am I doing wrong or, more likely, misunderstanding?

Comment: See the answer from @Adarsh below.  I had "height=100px" instead of "height:100px" in the style attribute.  Correcting the syntax fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BoCoKeith 
Please replace = with : in you second code

in `<tr style="height **=** changes to **:** ">`

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

I guess u can try changing table layout to fixed...
Cause maybe the row doesn't show 100px bcoz it's empty

Comment: Appreciate the thought, but I tried that; it didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have an issue with the quotations - You have a single set of quotes wrapped around the width and height so the computer thinks you're trying inline CSS. It should be:

```html
<tr id="topRow" style="width:100%;" height="100px"></tr>
```

Comment: No, that is exactly what I want to do.  I should be able to put both width and height in the same style tag.  Thanks for trying though.  See @Adarsh's answer below.

Comment: In that case, change your equals sign to a colon, you have improper CSS syntax. Sorry misunderstood what direction you were going in :)